# Custom function to check whether 2 HashMaps are equal is not working in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to check whether 2 HashMaps are equal using a custom function `match`. I expect the output to be `true`, but the program outputs `false`. Here is the code snippet.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapEquals{

    private static boolean matches1(HashMap<Character, Integer> one, HashMap<Character, Integer> two){
        for(char c: one.keySet()){
            if(one.get(c) != two.get(c))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean matches2(HashMap<Character, Integer> one, HashMap<Character, Integer> two){
        for(char c: two.keySet()){
            if(two.get(c) != one.get(c))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean matches(HashMap<Character, Integer> one, HashMap<Character, Integer> two){
        boolean first = matches1(one, two);
        boolean second = matches2(one, two);
        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(second);
        return (first && second);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        HashMap<Character, Integer> one = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Character, Integer> two = new HashMap<>();

        one.put('a', 10000);
        two.put('a', 10000);

        matches(one, two);
        System.out.println(one.equals(two));
    }
}
```

The output is

```
$ java HashMapEquals
  false
  false
  true
```

I know we can check the same functionality using the inbuilt function of hashmap `one.equals(two)` which is working as expected. But, I am just curious to know what is wrong with the custom function `matches` in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Objects.equals` instead of `==` or `!=` to compare non-primitives that might be `null`. Note that you should check that the two `Map`s have the exact same size instead of doing the value check both ways.

```java
if (!Objects.equals(one.get(c), two.get(c))) return false;
```